# Pyspark - Transpose multiple dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have multiple dataframes that look like this.

```
df1:

+---------+---------+---------+
|sum(col1)|sum(col2)|sum(col3)|
+---------+---------+---------+
|       10|        1|        0|
+---------+---------+---------+

df2:

+---------+---------+
|sum(col1)|sum(col2)|
+---------+---------+
|       20|        6|
+---------+---------+

df3:

+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|sum(col1)|sum(col2)|sum(col3)|sum(col4)|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|        1|        5|        3|        4|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

For the above example,the output should look like this.

```
+--------+------+------+------+
|col_name|value1|value2|value3|
+--------+------+------+------+
|    col1|    10|    20|     1|
|    col2|     1|     6|     5|
|    col3|     0|  null|     3|
|    col4|  null|  null|     4|
+--------+------+------+------+
```

I am using spark 1.6.3 to do this. In the above example, I have different sum calculation for a particular table but I have multiple tables to calculate sum for each of the table and output should be consolidated in the above format.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably easiest to do outside of pyspark, and if the data you are working with is small enough, that is probably what you should do because doing this is pyspark will not be especially efficient.

If for some reason you need to do this is pyspark, you can do this with several dataframe transformations. The first thing we need to do is convert all of the individual dataframes into the same schema which will allow us to iteratively select from each and union into a final result. The following is one way to achieve this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType

a = [[10,1,0]]
b = [[20,6]]
c = [[1,5,3,4]]

dfa = spark.createDataFrame(a,['col1','col2','col3'])
dfb = spark.createDataFrame(b,['col1','col2'])
dfc = spark.createDataFrame(c,['col1','col2','col3','col4'])

dfdict = {'dfa':dfa,'dfb':dfb,'dfc':dfc}
columns = set([col for dfname in dfdict for col in dfdict[dfname].columns])

for dfname in dfdict:
    for colname in columns-set(dfdict[dfname].columns):
        dfdict[dfname] = dfdict[dfname].withColumn(colname, lit(None).cast(StringType()))

schema = StructType([StructField("col_name", StringType(), True)]+\
                    [StructField("value_"+dfname, IntegerType(), True) for dfname in dfdict])
resultdf=spark.createDataFrame([],schema = schema)

for colname in columns:
    resultdf = resultdf\
                .union(dfdict['dfa'].select(lit(colname).alias('col_name'),
                       col(colname).alias('value_dfa'))\
                .crossJoin(dfdict['dfb'].select(col(colname).alias('value_dfb')))\
                .crossJoin(dfdict['dfc'].select(col(colname).alias('value_dfc'))))

resultdf.orderBy('col_name').show()

>>>

+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|col_name|value_dfa|value_dfb|value_dfc|
+--------+---------+---------+---------+
|    col1|       10|       20|        1|
|    col2|        1|        6|        5|
|    col3|        0|     null|        3|
|    col4|     null|     null|        4|
+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

There may be ways to improve efficiency of this by removing the cross joins and replacing them with something more clever.

If you need to work with starting dataframes that have multiple rows you would need to aggregate rows together (or change the requirements of the expected output). For instance, you may want to sum everything like the following example.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum

d = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
dfd = spark.createDataFrame(a,['col1','col2','col3'])

dfdagg = dfd.groupby().agg(*[sum(col) for colname in dfa.columns])
```

Where `dfdagg` can now be used in the same way that the other dataframes have been used above.

Answer (score 0):

In an alternative way, you can use stack function to transpose dfs then merge them

```
>>> df1x = df1.selectExpr("stack(3, 'col1', col1, 'col2', col2, 'col3', col3) as (col_name, value1)")
>>> df1x.show()
+--------+------+
|col_name|value1|
+--------+------+
|    col1|    10|
|    col2|     1|
|    col3|     0|
+--------+------+

>>> df2x = df2.selectExpr("stack(2, 'col1', col1, 'col2', col2) as (col_name, value2)")
>>> df2x.show()
+--------+------+
|col_name|value2|
+--------+------+
|    col1|    20|
|    col2|     6|
+--------+------+

>>> df3x = df3.selectExpr("stack(4, 'col1', col1, 'col2', col2, 'col3', col3, 'col4', col4) as (col_name, value3)")
>>> df3x.show()
+--------+------+
|col_name|value3|
+--------+------+
|    col1|     1|
|    col2|     5|
|    col3|     3|
|    col4|     4|
+--------+------+

>>> df1x.join(df2x, "col_name", "full").join(df3x, "col_name", "full").sort("col_name").show()
+--------+------+------+------+                                                 
|col_name|value1|value2|value3|
+--------+------+------+------+
|    col1|    10|    20|     1|
|    col2|     1|     6|     5|
|    col3|     0|  null|     3|
|    col4|  null|  null|     4|
+--------+------+------+------+
```